# Cannot override model once compiled

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am setting up a discord bot that saves server/user information on a MongoDB database. I am using the discord server ID for the collection name in the database models. When I try to save data to a collection using the same collection name (same server ID), I get the error saying that the model cannot be overridden once compiled. How do I fix this and still use the server ID as the collection name?

I have tried moving around the code to get it not to do this error. I want to use it in another file but I don't know how to send the server ID to the file for the collection name.

```js
async function addUserFile(usr) {
  const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: String,
    warnings: Array,
    moderations: Array,
    currency: String,
  })

  let userFile = mongoose.model(usr.guild.id, userSchema)

  let file = new userFile({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    userID: usr.id,
    warnings: {},
    modersations: {},
    currency: 0
  })

  file.save()
}
```

I want to get the documents to add to the collection using the ID of the server they come from without the error, but I get the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite model once compiled.` error instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using `delete mongoose.connection.model[collectionName]` after the document is saved or updated.